# Why does Python requests ignore the verify parameter?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, python-requests

## The problem

I have been trying to use Python's requests package to download the following URL:

> https://service.isracard.co.il/I_logon.jsp

In Chrome, the certificate seems valid:

[image]

However, in Python, the request fails with `SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE`, even when [using the `verify` flag](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) which ignores erroneous certificates:

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False

## Stack trace

```
>>> requests.__version__
'2.7.0'
>>> LOGIN_URL = 'https://service.isracard.co.il/I_logon.jsp'
>>> requests.get(LOGIN_URL, verify=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/sslenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/sslenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/sslenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/sslenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/sslenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

## Environment

### OS And packages

I'm using requests 2.7.0 and Python 2.7.10 in a virtual environment on OSX.

### cURL

cURL call to the same URL on the same machine works fine:

```
 $ curl -I https://service.isracard.co.il/I_logon.jsp
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2015 11:37:27 GMT
Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000R90MxFKBVxBMV665syGfjnh:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
Set-Cookie: Alt50_ZLinuxPrd=94742720.30755.0000; expires=Fri, 18-Sep-2015 12:07:19 GMT; path=/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-8
Content-Language: iw-IL
Set-Cookie: ServiceP=53323968.20480.0000; path=/
```

Comment: Note that `verify=False` *ignores* invalid certificates. This is not an invalid cert problem, this is a handshake failure, the verification could already have passed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Right! Missed that. Any idea why it fails?

Comment: Just a vague tip: I had a similar problem long ago: try to use a specific `ssl_version` (try several versions): http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#example-specific-ssl-version

Comment: Thanks. I think I will simply try another package.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Certificate validation did not fail, so the `verify` argument doesn't apply here. What failed is the cipher negotiation; none of the ciphers `requests` is willing to use match those the server is willing to use.

If you run your `curl` command with the `-v` switch you'll see what cipher suite was negotiated by `curl` for the successful connection:

```sh
$ curl -v -I https://service.isracard.co.il/I_logon.jsp
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.118.12.8...
* Connected to service.isracard.co.il (192.118.12.8) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
[ .... ]
```

That's the RC4-SHA cipher, which has [some rather troublesome securty issues](http://www.isg.rhul.ac.uk/tls/) and should not really be used; it offers no [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_forward_secrecy) for example. The `urllib3` package (bundled with `requests`) by default *excludes* that cipher from the default ciphers. You can add it back with:

```
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':RC4-SHA'
try:
    requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST += ':RC4-SHA'
except AttributeError:
    # no pyopenssl support used / needed / available
    pass
```

and your request works:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS += ':RC4-SHA'
>>> requests.get('https://service.isracard.co.il/I_logon.jsp')
<Response [200]>
```

I didn't install the pyOpenSSL package so I didn't bother with the `try..except` guarded part.

Comment: Oddly enough, it works on Ubuntu, not on OSX - any idea why?

Comment: @AdamMatan: I tested this on OSX, but with a Python built from source and with homebrew handling the OpenSSL library for me. There are two SSL libraries wrapped up in `requests.packages.urllib3`, each with their own copy of the string, I've added the pyopenssl package version too.

Answer (score 7):

I run into this as well on macOS Sierra, Python 2.7.9 and it is fixed by:

> sudo pip install --ignore-installed pyOpenSSL --upgrade

It's probably due to the pyOpenSSL is too old.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of OpenSSL upgrade and installing `ndg-httpsclient` resolved it for me

`sudo pip install ndg-httpsclient`

and

`sudo pip install --ignore-installed pyOpenSSL --upgrade`