# HTTP GET site which uses TLS1.1 with urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, urllib3

When I try to GET this site which uses the obsolete TLS1.1 with urllib3, this error is raised:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request('GET', 'https://site/')

SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:646)
```

It seems that urllib3 is trying to handshake with SSL3, but as I mentioned, this site uses TLS1.1.

Do I have to specify that I wan't to use TLS1.1? How do I do it?

I've found this parameter called [`ssl_version`](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html?highlight=ssl_version#module-urllib3.util.ssl_) (it can be passed in the PoolManager constructor) which defaults to `PROTOCOL_SSLv23`. But I did not found something like `PROTOCOL_TLSv11` in `urllib3.util.ssl_`. In fact, the only var that starts with `PROTOCOL_` is the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that urllib3 is trying to handshake with SSL3, but as I mentioned, this site uses TLS1.1.

The site still support SSL 3.0 (also TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1) so I doubt that this is the problem. I would suggest the problem is more that the server only supports the insecure cipher RC4-SHA which is excluded from the default cipher set of urllib3. 
See also [Why does Python requests ignore the verify parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650984/why-does-python-requests-ignore-the-verify-parameter).