# HandShake Failure in python(_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, urllib2, pycurl, sslhandshakeexception

When I execute the below line,

```
req = urllib2.Request(requestwithtoken) 
self.response = urllib2.urlopen(req,self.request).read()
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

The thing is I am able to get the token by pinging the service by using `curl`.
During the process of retrieving the token, all the certificates were verified.
In turn, by using the generated token, i am not able to connect to the service.
I am getting the above error while trying.
What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 12):

I was having the same issue. It's probably because your remote server requests cipher that isn't supported by urllib2. I think there're two solutions possible:

1. [Enable your specific cipher in `urllib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650984/why-does-python-requests-ignore-the-verify-parameter). I think you can also enable [all ciphers supported](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) (see the very bottom of the page) but rather check which one you're using with `curl` as shown in the link above.
2. Install `requests` with extra security packages using: `pip install requests[security]`. It's further discussed in this [requests issue on github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2022#issuecomment-75506581).

I did the second option and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Check which version of *requests* you are using.

```
import requests
print requests.__version__
```

If the version is 2.18.4, you should try downgrading to version 2.11.1. I did this, and it fixed my problem.
To do this, issue the following commands in the terminal

```
pip uninstall requests
pip install requests==2.11.1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Downgrading to 2.11.1 also worked on Mac (was at version 2.14.2).